# I'm making a program that finds a specific type of file and puts its name in a list, but

Tags: python, file

The problem in question is that I made a function to find a type of file, but every time I pass the result to the list it "overwrites" the other one in question, shown below

*Don't mind the prints, the code is pretty messed up, I use a separate track from the source code of the app I'm working on, like a scratch sheet*

`

```
for file in pathlib.Path("C:/Users/doppi/Onedrive").glob('**/*'):
        if file.suffix in pattern:
            highschool.insert(0, str(file))

print(highschool, "\n\n")   

for i in range(len(highschool)):
    po.insert(0, highschool[i].split('\\'))

for i in range(0, len(po)):
    b = []
    for l in range(0, len(po[i])):
        b =  format(po[i][l].find('.mp3'))  
        musiclist = []
        if(int(b) >= 0):
            **musiclist.insert(0, str(po[i][l]))**
```

`

The output of the musiclist variable is this here (*I have two mp3 files*)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMst0.jpg)
But when you go to the second song, what comes out is just this one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue4Yi.jpg)

I expected the two files to appear in the list, I tried a lot to solve it for myself, but it's very difficult
*Sorry for bad english, I don't speak that language well*

Thanks in advance for reading this far

Comment: What is `po`? Your code uses it but its definition isn't included.

Comment: Not sure of what you want to do exactly,  but it seems to me that you must be aware of the fact that a split returns an array.   maybe you should have :    po.insert(0, highschool[i].split('\\')[0]) to get each name of your previous list, not a [name]